# How to validate Image in admin custom form in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, javascript, validation

I create custom form in admin panel in magento.Here I tried in many way to validated image tags in admin panel.

> /app/code/community/**company_name/module_name**/Block/Adminhtml/**module_name**/Edit/Tab/image.php

my Image tag containing code :

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /**
         * Checking if user have permissions to save information
         */
        if (Mage::helper('magentostudy_news/admin')->isActionAllowed('save')) {
            $isElementDisabled = false;
        } else {
            $isElementDisabled = true;
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('news_image_');

        $model = Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->getNewsItemInstance();


        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_fieldset', array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image Thumbnail'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
        ));

        $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);

        $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image',
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_news_edit_tab_image_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Here I put class required value and also gives `'required'  => true,` in my form.

**Updated:**

Here, same functionality can be applied in text box, it working fine ..

Here path location for text box.

> /app/code/community/**company_name/module_name**/Block/Adminhtml/**module_name**/Edit/Tab/Main.php

and also working fine in this coding....

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->getNewsItemInstance();

        /**
         * Checking if user have permissions to save information
         */
        if (Mage::helper('magentostudy_news/admin')->isActionAllowed('save')) {
            $isElementDisabled = false;
        } else {
            $isElementDisabled = true;
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('news_main_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Item Info')
        ));

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('news_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'news_id',
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'name'     => 'title',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Title'),
            'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Title'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('author', 'text', array(
            'name'     => 'author',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Model Id'),
            'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Model Id'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ));
 [...............]
```

and also I attached my text box validation.
[image: Sample validation working function]

Same functionality is implement in file type, but not working in file type. I just putting `class =>'required-entry',`it not working well,Please guide me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files you can use the class `required-file`. So add that to the `class` index of the addField array

```
[...]
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
    'name'      => 'image',
    'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
    'required'  => true,
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
));
[...]
```

Checkout [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/) by Inchoo on validations to learn more about the different types

**[EDIT]**

I recommend also doing some checks in the controller that handles the post to check for the appropriate file types etc. Javascript validation is by no means bulletproof.

Comment: Hi @Sander...i check it out your answer,It not works for me... and also I update my question.Can you please guide me..

Comment: I'll check it later on, don't have the time right now so hang in there :)

Comment: Thank you @Sander...I am waiting for your valuable answer..

Comment: I did a quick check myself on an existing extension and adding the class and required=true values as described in my answer worked. Can you make sure both values are set correctly?

Comment: Hi @Sander...I check it out with your answer, but it still replies no validation in file type.i doesnt gave class in my textbox but i validated correctly..how is it possible...i get  this custom extension from this links info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magentostudy_News.zip

Comment: just saying it's required will perform basic validation (i.e. is the value present), however for an image you need a bit more validation that's what the `required-file` class is for. If this isn't working I think that there is a bigger issue here which I'm not able to spot at the moment. I suggest contacting the extension developer on this.

Comment: Hi @sander..I just want create custom extension in magento admin panel,its free tutorial(demo extension which is provided by magento developers) extension, How to create images upload with validation. can you provide some other idea for this..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10844/discussion-between-sander-mangel-and-vivek-mdu)