# Validation does not work in admin forms

Tags: adminform, form-validation

I followed the advices of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8785/9489 and succeed to get that :

```
        $fieldsetImage->addField('logo_big', 'image', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Logo'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Logo'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',
            'required'  => Mage::getStoreConfig('clzbrands/general/logo'),
            'name'      => 'logo_big',
            'value'     => $brand->getLogoBig()
        ));
```

Unfortunately, the html is not generated as expected and I get that :

```
<tr>
  <td class="label">
   <label for="logo_big">
    Logo<span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
  </td>
  <td class="value">
    <input id="logo_big" class="input-file" type="file" title="Logo" value="" name="logo_big">
  </td>
</tr>
```

[image: The display]

I use a magento 1.9.2 ce without any other module than the one i develop.

The display is correct but I would love to have this validation work. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: try by set required to true directly

Comment: I tried. The display is good, the field is marked as required but in the facts, I can leave it empty and raise an exception on server-side validation.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to accomplish does not seem possible using the  'image' type.

If you take a look at /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Text.php you will notice that in order to add user defined classname you need to call `this->addClass('input-text');` (see /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php) which is not called in /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php

To accomplish what you trying :

**1) Create your own type that extend image**

Eg

```
class MagePal_MyImage_Lib_Varien_Data_Form_Element_Customimage extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image
{


}
```

Then in your form

```
 $fieldset->addType('customtype', 'MagePal_MyImage_Lib_Varien_Data_Form_Element_Customimage');

 $fieldset->addField('field_id', 'customtype', array(
 'label' => $helper->__('Field label'),
 'name' => 'field_name'
 ));
```

*I think the issue may be in /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php `getElementHtml()` see $this->setClass('input-file');*

See  [Magento admin form fieldset custom type](http://www.atwix.com/magento/admin-form-fieldset-custom-type/)

**2) Use javascript to add the class**

```
$fieldsetImage->addField('logo_big', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Logo'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Logo'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'logo_big',
        'value'     => $brand->getLogoBig()
    ))->setAfterElementHtml("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$('logo_big').addClassName('required-entry');</script>");;
```

Comment: Your help was great as it helped me to find out that it exists a type called imagefile and that fits exactly what I need. Therefore, I do not understand the need of the type image but I will check later.

Comment: "Image type" will show you a preview of the current image uploaded and also allow you to delete the image.